# Application crashed with event name CLR20r3?

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, visual-studio-2013

My application crashed on customer's machine with the following message
My application use WPF, C# and C++.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: mysticserver.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 544d0baf
  Problem Signature 04: PresentationCore
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.30319.17929
  Problem Signature 06: 4ffa6e63
  Problem Signature 07: 283
  Problem Signature 08: 13
  Problem Signature 09: PSZQOADHX1U5ZAHBHOHGHLDGIY4QIXHX
  OS Version:   6.2.9200.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 5a52
  Additional Information 2: 5a5202200b903e0c10739d8f4ac14d23
  Additional Information 3: 673b
  Additional Information 4: 673b5a7aa113d7eec5a03fb51cac71b0

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=190175

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Someone can tell me, how to determine the error?

```
UPDATE:
```

I'm sure that on the client machine, that installed `.Net 4.5 full package` the same .net version with all project configurations. And the machine client installed `Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2013`.

I'm using `visual studio 2013` to develop the application.

Many thanks!

Comment: Since its not your machine. Think what is different? What .net you use and what is actually running? It writes prrsentationcore. Something in wpf maybe. Check all package are intalled on clients machine

Comment: Please see may update above, thank you!

Comment: Does it crash on other computers too or just one?

Answer (score 2):

It can be caused either by [some registry errors](http://www.sevenforums.com/software/323079-program-has-stopped-working-problem-event-name-clr20r3.html) which can be fixed by running a registry clean up software or entering the following commands:

```
regsvr32 atl.dll
cd C:\WINDOWS\eHome
ehSched /unregServer
ehSched /service
ehRecvr /unregServer
ehRecvr /service
ehRec.exe /unregServer
ehRec.exe /regserver
ehmsas.exe /unregServer
ehmsas.exe /regserver
```

Or caused by a mismatched version of .Net framework ([sometimes client version doesn't work and you have to install the full version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227462/services-crashed-with-event-name-clr20r3)) or other prerequisites. Try re-installing .Net framework.

If the problem lingers after that, it might be something wrong with OS.

Comment: Please see may update above, thank you!