# WPF application error event: CLR20r3, module: mscorlib

Tags: wpf, mscorlib

I have an application in WPF The application closes periodically in client computer, in development it never happens. The following is the error in the windows event viewer

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: No disponible
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: App.exe
P2: 1.0.0.0
P3: d2b32ca9
P4: mscorlib
P5: 4.7.3416.0
P6: 5cabfaa3
P7: 3ae2
P8: 0
P9: System.AccessViolationException
P10:
```

Any ideas, this error doesn't happen every day
Thanks

**UPDATE**
More info from event log Source .Net Runtime

```
 Versión de Framework: v4.0.30319
Descripción: el proceso terminó debido a una excepción no controlada.
Información de la excepción: System.AccessViolationException
   en System.Collections.Hashtable.GetHash(System.Object)
   en System.Collections.Hashtable.InitHash(System.Object, Int32, UInt32 ByRef, UInt32 ByRef)
   en System.Collections.Hashtable.ContainsKey(System.Object)
   en System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdateChildrenInternal(Int32)
   en System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdateSubtree()
   en System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdateSubtree()
   en System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdateSubtree()
   en System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdateSubtree()
   en System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireAutomationEvents()
   en System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   en System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(System.Object)
   en System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   en System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(System.Object)
   en System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.AnimatedRenderMessageHandler(System.Object)
   en System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   en System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   en System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   en MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(System.Object)
   en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   en MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   en System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   en System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   en System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   en MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   en MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   en System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   en System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   en System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   en MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   en MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   en System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   en System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   en System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   en  MyApp.App.Main()
```

Comment: mscorlib is one of the main .NET modules. make sure you have installed prerequisites on the target machine. BTW you must provide debugging details. what OS, framework, version, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the cause of System.AccessViolationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133971/finding-the-cause-of-system-accessviolationexception)

Comment: Hi @Bizhan, in debug I have no errors, the exception is not triggered. I have configured DispatcherUnhandledException, UnobservedTaskException, and UnhandledException. The client machines the client's machines have w10. Target Framework 4.7.2. Platform x64

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26623084/366064 registry errors or null reference in DLLImport may be the causes

Comment: Debug is presumably on your machine and this has the "correct" version of com control or data or you're not running it for 8 hours and doing precisely whatever the user did to get into that state.

Comment: I've been testing for more than a day and I'm not getting the error. On the client's pc, sometimes up to a week passes without the error occurring. The last thing I have done is update the client's pc to netframework 4.8